# How to count ratios of two column values by group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a list of flights as a pandas dataframe like this:

```
airline        status          number    ...

Aer Lingus     some error A        14    ...
Aeroflot       success             47    ...
Air Canada     success              2    ...
Air Dolomiti   success              2    ...
Air Europa     some error B         4    ...
Air France     success             40    ...
Alitalia       some error A        10    ...
....
```

I make some api calls for each flight which either succeeds or gives an error.

What I would like to have is the ratio of success for each airline. So I know that I can count the occurrences of the values in column "airline" and "status" with groupby, but I fail to do this for the ratio of the values.

```
def calculate_quote_success_ratios(flights):

    success_ratio_per_airline = flights.groupby(['airline', 'status']).count()
    # TODO: Include ratio with failures!

    return success_ratio_per_airline
```

the expected output should be something like this:

```
airline        success_ratio

Aer Lingus     0.72
Aeroflot       0.845
Air Canada     0.935
Air Dolomiti   0.5
Air Europa     ...
....
```

**Edit**: To be clear, the column `df['numbers']` is not relevant. So I only want to count the percentage of "successes" to all sorts of errors for each airline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) with `normalize='index'`:

```
# data from @Chris

res = pd.crosstab(df['airline'], df['status'], values=df['number'],
                  aggfunc='count', normalize='index')

print(res[['success']])

status       success
airline             
AerLingus        0.5
Aeroflot         1.0
AirCanada        1.0
AirDolomiti      1.0
AirEuropa        0.0
AirFrance        0.5
Alitalia         0.5
```

Comment: I am sorry, I think I was very unclear. I want to calculate the ratio of occurences, so the column "number" in my dataframe is not relevant. For example, if airline A has 5 sucesses and 5 failures, I want to have a row: "airline A, 0.5"

Comment: Ok, thanks. What is the "values" parameter for? I was confused because the number column is not relevant

Comment: `aggfunc='count'` needs *something* to count, we just count the *number* of non-`NaN` values in `df['number']`. The numbers inside `df['number']` aren't used / relevant.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how I would add the total number of occurences to each airline?

Comment: @Ipsider, `crosstab` supports only one `aggfunc`. You can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have other requirements.

Answer (score 3):

group wise count of number of flights

```
count_flight=df.groupby('airline').status.count()
```

group wise count of number of successes

```
count_success=df[df['status']=='success'].groupby('airline').status.count()
```

pandas div return groupwise ratio of two previous dataframes.

```
count_success.div(count_flight).fillna(0)
```

Comment: please provide an explanation to your code to improve the quality of your answer

Answer (score 2):

I had to modify your example for it to work but you can simply just do `df.groupby(['airline', 'status']).sum() / df.groupby(['airline']).sum()`

original df:

```
airline           status    number
0   Aer Lingus  some error A    14
1   Aeroflot    success 47
2   Air Canada  success 2
3   Air Dolomiti    success 2
4   Air Europa  some error B    4
5   Air France  success 40
6   Alitalia    some error A    10
7   Alitalia    success 10
8   Air France  some error B    10
9   Aer Lingus  success 12



df.groupby(['airline', 'status']).sum() / df.groupby(['airline']).sum()

                                  number
airline         status  
Aer Lingus     some error A     0.538462
               success          0.461538
Aeroflot       success          1.000000
Air Canada      success         1.000000
Air Dolomiti    success         1.000000
Air Europa    some error B      1.000000
Air France    some error B      0.200000
              success           0.800000
Alitalia      some error A      0.500000
              success           0.500000
```

Comment: That's not working for me. Maybe I was a bit unclear. The column "numbers" is not relevant. So I only want to count the percentage of "successes" to all sorts of errors for each airline. Your code looks very promising and I thought that's it but it does not seem to work for me... thank you though!

Comment: @Ipsider I am sorry; I thought that the `number` column was the number of occurrences of each status

Comment: @Ipsider if you only care about the count of occurrences of each status you could do the same thing but instead of `.sum()` use `.count()`

Comment: Ahh got it. Sorry for the confusing example!

Answer (score 1):

For you this will work.

I am making a small change to the correct marked answer.

res = pd.crosstab(df['airline'], df['status'], values="",
aggfunc='count', normalize='index')

print(res[['success']])

Comment: You should provide clear explanation to why you're suggesting this change and what benefit it adds.

Answer (score 1):

A single line code that doesn't refer to the name of frame again.
For just in case this thing is applied in continuation to some other command and frame might not have any name at that moment. Or someone likes to write single line commands

```
# Using @Chris's dataset
      airline          status      number
0    Aer Lingus  some error A      14
1      Aeroflot       success      47
2    Air Canada       success       2
3  Air Dolomiti       success       2
4    Air Europa  some error B       4
5    Air France       success      40
6      Alitalia  some error A      10
7      Alitalia       success      10
8    Air France  some error B      10
9    Aer Lingus       success      12


df.groupby(by = ['airline', 'status'])['status'].count().unstack(level = -1, fill_value = 0)/
.apply(lambda row: row['success']/row.values.sum(), axis = 1)


print(df)

airline
Aer Lingus      0.5
Aeroflot        1.0
Air Canada      1.0
Air Dolomiti    1.0
Air Europa      0.0
Air France      0.5
Alitalia        0.5
dtype: float64
```

You might put some comments in between the continuous commands to understand better.